# sbpl_lattice_planner loading move_base plugin fails

Tags: navigation, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl, global-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to setup my nav config to use `pose_follower` as my local planner (so i can have backwards movements) and then reading around, people say NavFn doesnt work with pose_follower. So i read around and saw people where saying to use sbpl_lattice_planner with pose_follower, so i tried to add it as a plugin to use with move base. For some reason im getting a really wierd error when i launch move_base (the full log can be viewed in [a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EFz8a5Fg) i made to not clutter the question. But the primary part of the error log is this:

```
process[move_base-1]: started with pid [9692]
[ WARN] [1428337418.710189086, 9.812000000]: Waiting on transform from base_link to odom to become available before running costmap, tf error:
[ INFO] [1428337418.724891841, 9.826000000]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1428337418.777851298, 9.878000000]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1428337418.840831680, 9.939000000]:     Subscribed to Topics:
[ INFO] [1428337418.889993790, 9.989000000]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1428337419.030963854, 10.131000000]: Name is SBPLLatticePlanner
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SBPL_Exception*'
[move_base-1] process has died [pid 9692, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/move_base /odom:=/odometry/filtered __name:=move_base __log:=/home/parallels/.ros/log/3216eba8-dc79-11e4-9dbf-001c42dabd93/move_base-1.log].
[move_base-1] restarting process
```

I did the following to install/use sbpl_lattice planner as a plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-sbpl
```

As when i install `sbpl` [from source](https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl), it installs the files into `/usr/local` (i think i might be doing something wrong) and then therefore when i clone the [sbpl_lattice_planner source](https://github.com/meyerj/sbpl_lattice_planner) and compile it via catkin_make it cant properly link the libspl shared libraries because its looking for it in /opt/ros/share/sbpl instead.

So after i install the sbpl ros debian, I clone the `sbpl_lattice_planner` source into my workspace, and compile successfully.

Then `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core` shows sbpl_lattice_planner is loaded as a plugin, and inside the `bgp_plugin.xml` i find that

```
<class name="SBPLLatticePlanner" type="sbpl_lattice_planner::SBPLLatticePlanner"...
```

So i use `SBPLLatticePlanner` as the name for the move_base parameter `base_global_planner`to look like so:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="true" name="move_base" output="screen">

    <remap from="/odom" to="/odometry/filtered" />

    <param name="base_local_planner" value="pose_follower/PoseFollower"/>
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="SBPLLatticePlanner"/>

    <param name="SBPLLatticePlanner/primitive_filename" value="$(find sbpl)/matlab/mprim/pr2.mprim" />

    <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find test_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find test_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find test_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find test_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
#    <rosparam file="$(find test_2dnav)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find test_2dnav)/pose_follower_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Would anyone happen to know if im missing something/mis-configuring something? I know you must load a primitives file (which was the first issue i overcame).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206703/sbpl_lattice_planner-loading-move_base-plugin-fails/) by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1526 on 2015-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @balamesh I figured out how to get sbpl_lattice_planner running on indigo. Seems like there where some missing symbols on initialization of sbpl_lattice_planner when loading it into move_base as a global planner plugin.

You can view a working version for indigo here: https://github.com/MASKOR/maskor_navigation

Make sure you use both the sbpl and sbpl_lattice_planner from source from that repo, as the normal sbpl does not link libraries correctly for sbpl_lattice_planner use

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2